# Using scipy optimization library for many parameters

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I want to maximize the return value of a function having fifty variables;

```
def function_to_maximize:
    return (7.9*a1 + 8.1*a2 + 0.4*a3 + ........ + 2.6*a50)
```

My variables are 0 <= aN <= 10, and the sum of my variables are 100.

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with this kind of tasks. By googling I found out that I can use this [documantation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) to get the job done but I could not figure out how to use the library.

Would you please provide a sample code with simple comments that tell the steps I have to apply?

Comment: Have you tried with only a few variables? What were the hurdles?

Comment: @Benjamin first of all I want to do a maximization but the documentation talks about minimization. There must be a trick to find the maximum values. And also there are lots of headers, algorithms. I'm not sure which one is right for me to follow. Are they just different implementations to minimize a function?

Comment: Yes, they are different algorithms. Some support constraints, some do not. If you take the general minimize function scipy will chose one automatically. Just check the docs and examples. Your problem is trivial. And remember: max (7*a1 + 8*a2) == min(-7*a1 -8*a2). **Edit:** the best approach here is to use Linear programming (which is the most limited approach with the best solvers in general). In scipy there is linprog, but it's bad. But you may try it!

Comment: Wouldn't the max occur when the 10 largest multiplicative factors all get a value of 10 in the variable (and the others zero)?

Comment: Of course not @Benjamin. 10000*a1+0.1*a2+0.1*a3+0.1*a4+0.1*a5+0.1*a6+0.1*a7+0.1*a8+0.1*a9+0.1*a10+0?

Comment: @sascha thanks for the comment, I will have a look at linprog. The maximization point is clear for me!

Comment: @anilca: Your new example says: `x=[1e4, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1]`. I say that choosing `a=[10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]` will meet your criteria of summing to 100, not exceeding 10, and maximize the function `y = ax` with a value of 100009. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `symfit`, a wrapper I made for `scipy`, this becomes a lot easier to implement. So please forgive me for recommending you give it a try. You can find the documentation here: http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitting_types.html#minimize-maximize

In your case; I would do the following:

```
from symfit import parameters, Maximize, Equality

# Make your 50 parameters to optimize and their coefficients.
aN = parameters(', '.join('a{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 51)))
coeff = [7.9, 8.1, ..., 2.6]

model = sum(coeff_i * a_i for a_i, coeff_i in zip(aN, coeff))
fit = Maximize(model, constraints=[Equality(sum(aN), 100)])
fit_result = fit.execute()
```

Done!

p.s. I am worried that this is an underdetermined system of equations right? But that is for you to worry about :).